# NextJS 13 route does not work when including POST, PATCH, DELETE handlers on Amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I'm having issues running an application built using NextJS 13.4.12 and hosting on Amplify.

I have a simple route.ts file and am using the named handlers that Next JS 13 requires. The route below works as expected on local, however, when I run this on Amplify even accessing the GET endpoint directly in the browser does not work (500).

After playing around with it I've found out the endpoint works on Amplify if only the GET handler is there (commenting out the others) - any ideas why this might be?

I'm considering switching to a previous version of NextJS

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function GET () {
    return NextResponse.json({ impacts: ["one", "two", "three"] })
}

export async function POST () {
    return NextResponse.json({ test: true })
}

export async function PATCH () {
    return NextResponse.json({ test: true })
}

export async function DELETE () {
    return NextResponse.json({ test: true })
}
```

I've tried removing all the handlers other than GET which works, however, I need to be able to run the request making other types of request POST, PATCH, DELETE